# Access to WriteOnly Property

Tags: c#, properties, writeonly

I have a base class that is written in VB.net. This base class has a property. I have a C# class that is drived from that vb class. I need to set property here so I can give a value on to it. 
This is my property in vb.net class:

```
  Public MustInherit Class FTPDownloaderBase

   Public WriteOnly Property FilesToDownload() As ArrayList
    Set(ByVal Value As ArrayList)
        _filesToDownload = Value
    End Set
  End Property
```

this is my C# class:

```
 public class FTPDownloaderClass:FTPDownloader.FTPDownloaderBase
{



  public Array FilesToDownloadC
  {
      get
      {
          return base.FilesToDownload;
      }


  }
```

}

But I get this error on the line:  return base.FilesToDownload;
The property or indexer 'FTPDownloded.FtpDownloderbase.FilesToDownload' cannot be used in this context beacuse it lacks the get accessor.

How I can get access to this property and give a value to it in my C# code?

Solution:
I have add a Get to the VB base class and it is accessible now like this:

```
  Public Property FilesToDownload() As ArrayList
    Get
        Return _filesToDownload
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As ArrayList)
        _filesToDownload = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access the property if it doesn't have a `get` accessor, unless you use reflection.

The easiest solution would be to add the `Get` accessor to the VB Class, or to make `_filesToDownload` protected instead of private.

If you can not change the base class:

```
return typeof(FTPDownloader.FTPDownloaderBase).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic).Single(f => f.Name == "_filesToDownload").GetValue(this);
```

Comment: Thanks charpler, I havn't think I can add get to the base class, I have added     Public Property FilesToDownload() As ArrayList
        Get
            Return _filesToDownload
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As ArrayList)
            _filesToDownload = Value
        End Set
    End Property

and it works, Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify the base class and either add a get accessor, or add a method to return the property.